# How to disable snippets for other languages than the current language of editing file in VSCode

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

As my title, when I'm editing an HTML file, my VSCode suggestion shows both snippets for HTML and Javascript, and in some cases, snippets for JS show up at top of the suggestion list.
[image]

I feel it is a little annoying. So how can I get snippet suggestions for the current editing language only?

Answer (score 0):

You can create or edit your own snippets with "User Snippets". It's under File (Windows)/code (Mac) > Preferences, and then select the language.

Comment: Thank you but I don't want to create my snippets. The snippets can be vscode built-in snippets or come from an extension or be my own but I don't care about where it comes from. I just want to vscode show appropriate snippets for each language.